# Setup bandsaw for straight cut

Tags: cutting, band-saw

I recently started to work with the bandsaw. the problem is the cutting line moves/bends after 2-3 inches. what is the problem and please help to fix that ?!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The link Graphus provides covers the topic very well. To summarize, dull blade and to fast a feed rate